# change colors of some rows in dbgrid delphi 5

Tags: delphi-5, tdbgrid

I have a problem, I have an TStringList object with some numbers and his status in some kind of json text I created, like: {'8987436','Sin documentar.', '0','1'}, {...},...

This file can contain a lot of groups of data. This works really fine, this information I displayed in a DBGrid, only the numbers.

The problem is that when I try to change the color of the rows, only draw the color of the last number added to the dbgrid, and I need that each row with some type of number draw in yellow, other kind in red, other kind in green and all the other let it white. The other problem is that when I click on one row it refresh the dbgrid and paint it again in white.

I created this procedure:

```
procedure TEmbarqueGeneracionEscaneoFRM.DBValidasDrawColumnCell(
  Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn;
  State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  inherited;
  if Pinta then
    begin
      with (Sender As TDBGrid).Canvas do
        begin
          brush.Color:=GridColor;
          FillRect(Rect);
          TextOut(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Column.Field.AsString);
        end;
      TDBGrid(sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, Datacol, Column, State);
    end;
  Pinta := false;
end;
```

Where Pinta is a variable that tell if the number was painted, and GridColor is a TColor variable with the color that will be drawn.

Did you have any idea?

Regards